# align the asterisk mark near the label in a flex form?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have to add * mark for required fields in my application. I have done this by the code

```
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormItem label="Name" required="true">
            <mx:TextInput id="Name" width="200" editable="true"/>
        </mx:FormItem> 
        <mx:FormItem label="priority" required="true">
            <mx:ComboBox id="priorityId" width="200" cornerRadius="4" dataProvider="{customerPriorityList}" />         
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
<mx:VBox>
```

but the problem is that the * mark comes near the text input field or near the combo box. But i want that * mark near the label only as per my application.
I tried my best but failed.
Is there any way???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you tried?  Which version of Flex are you using?  This should be a lot easier with a Spark form and a custom skin than it is with the MX Forms.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<mx:Form width="30%">
    <mx:HBox horizontalGap="0">
        <mx:Label text="First Name"/>
        <mx:Label width="11" color="0xFF0000" text="*"/>
        <mx:Spacer width="20"/>
        <mx:TextInput/>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Form>
```